# one single large table or many small tables in mysql database implementation

Tags: mysql

I am building a database schema in which i have to store the notifications associated with a user. Should i create separate table for each user or i should have one single large table in MySQL database.
Which one is more efficient in terms of time and memory.

For single table, schema for notification table
is

```
Notification(NotificationID,UserId,Content,seen,..)
```

and for multiple tables, schema is

```
Notification__userId(NotificationID,Content,seen..)
```

Which will be created for each user once the user signups.

Comment: I would prefer one table

Comment: Use one table. When you have as many users as facebook, you might start to think differently

Answer (score 2):

Use a single table and set the correct indexes.

Using multiple tables makes the data handling more complicated and causes more individual points of failure in your application (creating the table, deciding which one to use, weird querybuilding etc.).

You might be scared by using a single table the execution times of queries will become slow, but you are underestimating the scaling capabilities of the database when the indexes are set correctly.

You might want to check out this site for some information about scalability and to learn about indexes: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/testing-scalability/data-volume

Answer (score 1):

U should use one table to store notification using userid that will help you to save every users notification and even will make it easy to fetch the data